# Pyspark kernel error while running jupyter notebook on Amazon EMR cluster

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm new in AWS EMR. I would like to run jupyter notebook on my cluster from command line with pyspark kernel.
To create cluster I ran command as follows:

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label emr-5.32.0 --name 'spark_jupyter_2'
--applications Name=Hadoop Name=Spark Name=Livy Name=JupyterEnterpriseGateway Name=Hive 
--ec2-attributes KeyName=…………..,InstanceProfile=EMR_EC2_DefaultRole --service-role EMR_DefaultRole 
--instance-groups InstanceGroupType=MASTER,
InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m5.xlarge InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m5.xlarge 
--region eu-central-1 --log-uri s3://………….../logs/ --no-termination-protected
```

Then I installed jupyter with `sudo pip3 install jupyter`

Then I signed in again with `ssh -i "…………...pem" -L 8888:localhost:8888 hadoop@ec2-…………..compute.amazonaws.com`

,ran command `jupyter notebook` and went to webpage from the link on the screen.

Until this step everything went smoothly but when I tried to run notebook with pyspark kernel I got ``kernel error```

I don't completely understand why is that. When I run `pyspark` from command line there's no error.

What do I have to do to run jupyter with pyspark kernel without any errors?
1.

Comment: Can you maybe tell us more details about the error? Any Cloudwatch logs or something like that?